# SIFT detects 0 keypoints?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, push-back

I'm creating the visual histograms (following the [Bag of Visual Words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model_in_computer_vision) model) of a dataset of `n` images using OpenCV.

This is the code:

```
    std::vector<std::string> fileList;
    std::unique_ptr<cv::BOWImgDescriptorExtractor> bowDE;
    cv::Mat vocabulary;//will be filled through KMeans
    ...
    bowDE->setVocabulary(vocabulary);
    cv::Ptr<cv::Feature2D> featureDetectorDescriptor = cv::xfeatures2d::SIFT::create(0,3,0.04,10,1.6);;
    for(size_t i=0;i<n;i++) {
        cv::UMat img;
        cv::Mat word;
        imread(fileList[i], cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE).copyTo(img);
        std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> keyPoints;
        featureDetectorDescriptor->detect(img, keyPoints);
        bowDE->compute(img, keyPoints, word);
        histograms.push_back(word);
        assert(histograms.rows==(i+1));//this is for testing
    }
```

The problem is that after `4625` images have been inserted, the `assert` condition is false. I tested `keypoints.size()` and it results 0, no keypoints are detected!

I tried to remove the image which created the error, but another one creates the same error (so the error seems not to depend from the image).

Why this happens?

**Update**: actually I found out that the error was image dependent. It seems that with the default parameters `cv::SIFT` detects 0 keypoints with this image from [Caltech101](http://www.vision.caltech.edu/Image_Datasets/Caltech101/):

[image]

Comment: It looks like you're asking for 0 features in your call to `create`

Comment: Yes that is very dependent on the image and the SIFT parameters you choose.

Comment: @Photon `0` means "detect the best number of features"

Comment: Good to know, I didn't see that in the documentation.